# Powershell script doesn't return event log results based on where clause

Tags: powershell

I am new to powershell and found examples to display messages from the event log. The -match and -eq property don't seem to be working.   Below is my script which does not return any results. When I use -notmatch or -ne it displays correctly. I’ve tried many different variations of the code, but nothing has worked.

```
$sysEvent = Get-EventLog -LogName Application -Newest 300

$sysError = $sysEvent | where {$_entryType -match "Information"}

$sysError | Sort-Object EventID | Format-Table EventID, EntryType, Source, TimeWritten, Message -AutoSize
```

Comment: Looks like a simple typo: `$_.entryType` (mind the `.`).

Comment: That was it. Thanks so much!